# Open an Android Studio project in a new desktop

Tags: android, android-studio

Am using the latest version of Android Studio, so am working on project A but want to open a different project B in a in a new desktop using Windows + Tabs and switching between the desktops using CTRL + WIN + Right Arrow - for quick reusing of code.

Why won't my android studio app open in the second desktop? When i click the launcher it only loads but doesn't open. Is there a setting or a correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to **File>Settings>Appearance & Behavior>System Setting** then change **Project Opening** setting according to your need.
[image]